# Jquery Click Event on multiple var item

Tags: jquery

This one working:

```
$("#txtName", "#$txtEmail").focus(function () {
    //do somthing
});
```

This one not working:

```
var txtName = $("#txtName");
var txtEmail = $("#txtEmail");

((txtName , txtEmail)).focus(function () {
    //do nothing
});
```

Why? and how will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  ( you should use the `add`(http://api.jquery.com/add/) function).

`txtName.add(txtEmail).focus(...)`

or use dynamic approach. just add to the array.

`$.each([txtName ,txtEmail ],function (i,n){ do something with n })`

simple example : http://jsbin.com/IrOxEgEk/2/edit

```
ar a=$("span").eq(0);
var b=$("span").eq(1);
$.each([a ,b ],function (i,n){ 

  n.text(i);
})
```

## Also

your statement :

`$("#txtName", "#$txtEmail")` is working is incorrect.

**this** one is working :L

`$("#txtName,#$txtEmail")`

Answer (score 0):

this may help

```
var = "#txtName";
var txtEmail = "#txtEmail"; 

$((txtName, txtEmail)).focus(function ()
{
///do something
}
```